# Using Lists in functions

Tags: c#, list

I am currently developing a little text-adventure in c# but I am still pretty new to the language so I am having some issues.

For example, I am using a List to save the names of the plants in a farm. I am not sure why I am getting an error here:

```
public static void InitializeList()
    {
        List<string> plants = new List<string>();
        plants.Add("wheat");

    }
public static void plantCrop(string crop)
    {
        if (plants.Contains(crop.ToLower())) 
        {

        }
    }
```

The program tells me that `_plants_ doesn't exist in the current content`.

Can I fix this without removing the List from the function `InitializeList()`? I am calling the List first thing in the Main program.

Answer (score 1):

`plants` is a local variable. made it class member to access it from other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your plants list exists in the InitializeList context.
If you make a field you can access it from the other method.

```
private static List<string> plants;
public static void InitializeList()
{
    plants = new List<string>();
    plants.Add("wheat");
}
public static void plantCrop(string crop)
{
    if (plants.Contains(crop.ToLower())) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure it should be static, but definitely needs to be at a higher scope.

Comment: @juharr if the method "using" it is static there is little choice (apart from creating an instance of the enclosing class inside it's static method which seems weird). But I agree maybe the method either shouldn't be static too

Comment: @Sehnsucht Yep, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `plants` as member variable instead of local variable in method `InitializeList`.

```
List<string> plants = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Plants is a local variable in the method and you could not access it via different method.

Answer (score 0):

please define your list(Plants) as global. You can't you local variable that defined in a function in other functions.

```
var plants = new List<string>();
public static void InitializeList()
{
   plants = new List<string>();
   plants.Add("wheat");

}
public static void plantCrop(string crop)
{
  if (plants.Contains(crop.ToLower())) 
   {}
 }
```